# how to use base64binary in php

Tags: php, web-services, base64

I have accessed the following **http://www.webservicex.net/genericbarcode.asmx**

luckly i got the result too,but the result in the format of base64binary.

i dont know how to parse the result if any one knows and Please explain me how to use the base64binary and convert the encoded format into the image. 

  Thanks,
Praveen J

Answer (score 1):

`base64_decode` is the function you need. See [base64_decode() doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could use **base64_decode()**:

```
base64_decode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `base64_decode` function. an example is here http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data = <<<IMG
.... add your image base64 here.....
IMG;
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
print base64_decode(trim($data));
?>
```